# Linux IP adress cannot be accessed via ssh command

Tags: linux, ssh

In my Linux server I have 2 interfaces so the linux server can be accessed via Terminal by typing

```
ssh username@IP1
```

or `ssh username@IP2`

Every thing works fine until I restarted my server. Now I could only access the linux server via the first IP address.
I checked IP configuration (here I am connected to the server via my first IP address)`nano etc/network/interfaces`gives:

```
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.13
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.253
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 192.168.1.2


# The secondary network interface
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.14
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.253
        dns-nameservers 192.168.2.2
```

ifconfig shows that only eth0 is up so, so once I typed `nano /sys/class/net/eth1/operstate`I discovered that this interface(second IP adress) is down so I tried `ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.14 netmask 255.255.255.255 up` and then restarted my networking service and ifconfig shows that my interface is up and can be accessed via terminal, but my access is denied (`Permission denied, please try again`) once I tried `ssh username@192.168.1.14`what can I
do in order to be able to access the servers via terminal with this IP address

Comment: Please enable spell checking in your browser; sloppy questions always smell like "I don't really care" so why should we?

Comment: What do you mean with "my access is denied"? And what do your logs say about your login attempt?

Comment: once I type ssh username@IP the terminal ask me to give my password but then displayed that it is wrong some time timeout I tried now dmesg | grep eth and it gives eth0: link is not ready
                              eth1: link is not ready

Comment: Is the information from `dmesg` related to the problem? To find out, check the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to ping the second interface just to make sure there isn't something wrong with the network itself
2. Make sure that SSH Daemon is configured to listen on both ports.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  1.ping work 2.ssh config file shows:HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no ...what to change?

Comment: Does `netstat -tanp` show that the SSH daemon is listening to the correct IP addresses?

Comment: yes but it displays 192.168.1.14:445        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2339/smbd is that correct

Comment: The last thing `2339/smbd` means: This is the `smbd` process with PID 2339 (it's part of Samba). You need to look for `sshd` and `0.0.0.0:22`.

Comment: ps -A | grep sshd returns  2437 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 4739 ?        00:00:00 sshd

Comment: I tired the following  vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config-->add the two lines:ListenAddress IP1
ListenAddress IP2 --->Restart the sshd: with /etc/init.d/sshd restart--> netstat -tulpn | grep :22-->my servers is listening to the two interfaces but acces still denied

Comment: run the ssh client with `-v -v -v`. That will enable tons of debug output. Look why it fails. If you don't understand the output, edit your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I didnt understand what means run ssh with -v -v -v I but the sudo service ssh status command indcates that the service is running

Comment: Run the ssh **client** with `-v -v -v user@IP2` to get more information why it fails.

Comment: I Have a question once I restarted the server once again the connexion via the two IP address work again normaly but only for 10 min and then the same problem. What could be the problem? Is that can be related with memory issues?

Comment: As long as you refuse to give me any information about the problem (error messages, logs, etc), I can't help you.

Comment: sorry I didn't quite understand which informations have I to provide

Comment: ssh -v -v -v user@IP2 works and I can access the server via ssh with IP2 but this only I restarted the server, so it's like once I restart the server every things works ok but after some time the second interface work not more without having changing any thing in the interfaces configuration.

Answer (score 0):

i'm pretty sure that the problem is in this line:
    allow-hotplug eth1
change it to auto eth1, the interface should now start whenever the system starts.